# zend framework docker-compose stop

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, docker-compose

In a new Zend framework 3 skeleton project, `docker-compose up` stop at the following stage:
    zf_1  | [Tue Apr 17 21:39:18.715358 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

Try many times, please help, thanks!

The docker-compose.yml is by default:

```
zf:
  build: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - "8080:80"
  volumes:
   - .:/var/www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't changed anything in the `[project folder]/Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` file:

You should use `-d --build` parameters, as below:

```
$ docker-compose up -d --build
```

So the service can be rebuilt and run in the background.

After that, just use `$ docker-compose up -d` to start your service.